# C++ boost program slower on a different server

Tags: c++, performance, boost, amazon-ec2, ovh

I have been using amazon EC2 instances to run a C++ program. Its heaviest task is to launch a boost dijkstra algorithm. On my laptop (running on Ubuntu 15.04) and on the EC2 instances (Ubuntu 14.04) I had similar performances. A typical dijkstra would take 60ms. Interestingly enough, the type of EC2 instance would have low performance impact on a single Dijkstra run.

Now, I've just set up an OVH cloud server, runnning on Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed the same steps to install all the dependencies I need. The very same Dijkstra now takes 130ms to run.

Boost version is the same, as are my compiler options (I'm using -O3). I've tried different types of OVH instances (RAM oriented, CPU oriented). The timing remains unchanged.

I doubt that OVH cloud performance could be this bad. Any idea ideas about what I could have missed or tests that I could do to understand what is going on ?

Comment: Sadly I'm going to suggest running with profiling (yes, you saw that coming). Another nice source of surprise perf differences is locale configurations (although nothing you mentioned makes this very likely). Good luck

Comment: I've run a profiler (callgrind) on a small Dijkstra example...the outputs are pretty similar in terms of perf. I see that some libraries used have different versions (for example libstdc++.so.6.0.19 vs libstdc++.so.6.0.20). Also the same example as described above run with -O0 optimazation flag takes  1.5 sec (OVH) and 1.42 sec (laptop). Which is a much smaller diff than the x2 factor I get with O3...I'm stuck here.

Comment: You built the packages locally? The processors could be different (e.g. if one affords SSE4 and the other doesn't...). Check with `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and see if adding `-march=native` helps/causes the difference

Comment: most of the things I need, I get them through apt-get. I only built two libraries, which are protobuf and zmq. But I have set my timer around the dijkstra code, so I don't think they could have an influence there. -march=native in my compile options makes no difference, unfortunately. Finally, I've taken a fresh OVH server, on Ubuntu 15.10 this time. Doing the same configuration steps, I now have a slight improvement, down from 130ms to 110ms.

Comment: also, doing a lscpu command, I see that OVH server is using KVM as a Hypervisor vendor, and has no L3 cache. While my amazon EC2 instance uses Xen and has 30720K of L3 cache. I don't know if that could make any difference ?